# How many shards does a MongoDB cluster support?

Tags: mongodb

My colleague told me that a MongoDB cluster can have at max of 1024 shards. But I can't find this number in MongoDB documentation. Is this statement true for MongoDB? Here is the [MongoDB documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/limits/) I'm referring.

Comment: Do you really plan such a huge sharded cluster? Today an average computer has maybe 1TB HDD storage, 1024 shards would let to 1 PetaByte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB employee Stennie stated that he is not aware of a specific limit on number of shards.

Source: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/maximum-number-of-shards/98230